# Modify Dataframe Column with Array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have following dataframe:

```
+----------+ 
|col       | 
+----------+ 
|[1, 4, 3] | 
|[1, 5, 11]| 
|[1, 3, 3] | 
|[1, 4, 3] | 
|[1, 6, 3] | 
|[1, 1, 3] | 
+----------+
```

What I want is:

```
+----------+ 
|col_new   | 
+----------+ 
|[3, -1]   | 
|[4, 6]    | 
|[2, 0]    | 
|[3, -1]   | 
|[5, -3]   | 
|[0, 2]    | 
+----------+
```

=> Diff operator arr[n+1] - arr[n]

And I don't know how I should do it.

I thought I should do it with udf? I'm not really familiar with it but yeah I tried.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def diff(a):
    return [a[ii+1]-a[ii] for ii in range(a.__len__()-1)]

function = udf(lambda c: diff(c))
df.withColumn("col_new",function(col("col"))).show(20,False)
```

But yeah that didn't work of course since I need a list... but I want to use the power of dataframe...
Does someone have a hint for me?

Best Boendal

Comment: Why didn't that work, I mean what was the outcome?  Also, you are missing the datatype in your udf: `function = udf(lambda c: diff(c), ArrayType(IntegerType()))`, which will cause "col_new" to be null. Also: `df.withColumn("col_new",function("col")).show(20,False)` (remove the extra `col`)

Comment: your code should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is perfect. The only mistake is in your import statement which should be as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def diff(a):
    return [a[ii+1]-a[ii] for ii in range(a.__len__()-1)]

function = F.udf(lambda c: diff(c))
df.withColumn("col_new",function(F.col("col"))).show(20,False)
```

And you should be all good

**Updated**

To sum up more, I would suggest you **try not using `udf` functions as much as possible as they require data serialization and deserialization which would certainly reduce the processing efficiency**, you should always try using inbuilt functions as much as possible.

So simply saying you can use `array` and `col` functions as below to meet your requirement.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.array([(F.col("col")[i+1]-F.col("col")[i]) for i in range(2)]).alias("col_new")).show(20,False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a UDF that does what you need in plain python like this:

```
def diff(array):
     res = []
     for i in range(0, len(array) -1):
             res.append(array[i+1]-array[i])
     return res

import pyspark.sql.functions as fun
f=fun.udf(diff)
```

And this is how you apply it to your data:

```
d = sc.parallelize([[[1,4,3]], [[1,5,11]], [[1,3,3]]]).toDF(["col"])
d.show()
+----------+
|       col|
+----------+
| [1, 4, 3]|
|[1, 5, 11]|
| [1, 3, 3]|
+----------+

d.withColumn("new_col", f(d["col"])).drop("col").show()
+-------+
|new_col|
+-------+
|[3, -1]|
| [4, 6]|
| [2, 0]|
+-------+
```